# Unable to run unit test in Angular 5 - ng test

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-jasmine

While running **ng tes**t, I am getting error

"**Uncaught TypeError: Zone.__load_patch is not a function**".

I checked the source code in the debugger console in chrome, it is showing error ../zone.js/dist/async-test.js_global. It was worked earlier but now seems some of the dependencies got upgraded.

Dev Dependencies version:

```
@Angular/cli: 1.2.7,
@angular/compiler-cli:~5.2.0,
@types/jasmine:2.5.38,
@types/jasminenewd:~2.0.2,
@types/node:~6.0.60,
karma:~1.4.1,
karma-chrome-launcher:~2.1.1,
Karma-cli: ~1.0.1, 
karma-jasmine: ~1.1.0, 
ts-node: ^3.3.0, 
talent: ~4.5.0
```

Dependencies: 
    zone. js: ^0.8.4

Answer (score 0):

You're using quite a new zone.js with an Angular CLI that's very outdated. That can't be right. Use the zone.js matching your angular version.

Comment: Could you please let me know, what is the compatible version of Angular CLI and zone.js. Shall I upgrade the latest Angular CLI version?

Comment: It's always a good idea to upgrade to the latest CLI version, for various reaons like security and performance. But to answer your question, it's in the peer dependencies array in the package json of the angular version you're using together with your CLI. Check that package.json file in your node modules.

Comment: Thank you very much Arne. I upgraded my angular cli as well as downgraded the zone.js version. Finally, it's worked for me. Great!!